# Extract a variable from another variable in a FOR loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

```
:yes
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /P saizo="Introduzca el valor (en KB) minimo para realizar la busqueda: "
SET /A sss=%saizo%+0
IF %sss% EQU 0 (
    ECHO Valor invalido. Introduzca puros numeros.
    PAUSE
    CLS
    GOTO yes
)
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @fsize @file" >"tumtum.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (tumtum.txt) DO (
    SET ae=%%I
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%J IN ("!ae!") DO (
        SET fsf=%%J
        SET fnf=!ae:%fsf%=!
        ECHO !fnf!
    )
PAUSE
)
```

Description of the code: it asks you for a number (`SET /P`), then checks if it's a number and starts looking for the files on the path where it's being run. The machine needs to look for files that has a greater value (in KBs) and `ECHO` them. My only issue comes in the part of extracting both the size and full file name. Tried doing a `FOR /F "tokens=1,2"` but for files names with a space the values breaks up. What could be done to fix this?

Comment: I would suggest you not use `FORFILES` and use a `FOR /R` command to iterate the files.  `FORFILES` is extremely inefficient because it spawns a `cmd.exe` instance for every file it has to process.  Open up a command prompt and read the help for the `FOR` command: `FOR /?`.  Read the very last section about the command modifiers.

Comment: Not a solution, but the label `:yes` should be moved one down to not risk exceedance of the `setlocal` nesting limit…

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1,*delims= " %%I in ('forfiles /s /p u:\ /c "cmd /c echo @fsize @file"') do echo size: %%I name:%%J
```

See the documentation about `for` (`for /?` from the prompt).

Placing the `forfiles` command within single-quotes makes `for` run the command as a source of input data.

`Tokens=1*` means "choose the first token, delimited by any of the `delims` characters, and assign it to the metavariable" (`%I` in this case); Choose the remaining characters on the line and assign them to the next metavariable.

`forfiles` is very slow. You would probably be better off using a `dir/s/b` command to select the filenames and `%~zI` to show the size of the file whose name is `"%I"`

Comment: Thank you! This worked out, but now I'm missing the IF checking the file size > set size. By any chance, do you know what could be causing the error? Got almost same IF as the one I posted. Console crashes everytime I put the IF.
`FOR /F "tokens=1,*delims= " %%I IN ('forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @fsize @file"') DO (
 SET fsf=%%I
 SET fnf=%%J
 SET sai=%saizo%
 ECHO !fsf! !fnf!
 IF !fsf! GRT !sai! (ECHO Name: !fnf!, size: !fsf!)`

Comment: `GRT` should be `GTR`. Also, the parentheses appear mismatched. An equivalent statement would be `FOR /F ... ) DO  if %%I GTR %saizo% echo Name: %%J size: %%I`